# Seeking Help for getting climate variable data

Tags: climate, agriculture, meteorology

I am working on Agro-Meteorology for two semiarid Districts of my Province (Telangana, India)(Deccan Plateau of South India). I tried my best to find Relative Humidity/Dew Point Temperature from most of the Global Climate data providers across the web, but failed to find the exact search. I want it to calculate Throntwaite Equation. Can anyone suggest me how and where can I get it. My choice of spatial resolution is minimum 0.1 degree, temporal resolution is 1 month and duration from 1979 to present.